# show Numeric field in crystal report when using LinqToSQL?

Tags: c#, vb.net, crystal-reports-2010

i use vs2010 and use crystal report , i create a LinqToSqlClasses.dbml and added my view in it. i cant find my int (numeric) field in field explorer but all of varchar field is showing , how can i find them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i use dataclasses to create my reports . when fields dos not show in field explore go to your dataclasses and change type of your fields that not shown to nullable = false or change type of data in your dataclasses only . i did it and it works . i wish that help you to .